# Domain Cloaking using HTACCESS or PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I currently have a website which allows our clients with other domains to redirect their domains to our website and use some of our features.

My problem is our clients dont want their clients and customers know that they are being redirected to another site.

So my question  is, Is it possible to cloaking (using .HTACCESS or PHP) my domain such that the user will enter our clients' domain and be redirected to our site without the browser showing that they have been redirected?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Your customers will have to create A or CNAME DNS records pointing to your servers (CNAME is preferred so you can change the IP without your customers changing anything).

Then you need to configure your webserver to handle requests for their domains (`ServerAlias their.domain` in the VirtualHost).

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Just google [php proxy](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20proxy). This should do the trick for you.